# mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php

I am getting an annoying error on php saying

`Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\john\core\functions\users.php on line 16`

`Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\john\core\functions\users.php on line 24`

line 16 refers to

```
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("Select 'id' From 'users' where 'username'= '$username'"), 0 ,'id'));
```

and line 24 refers to

```
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("Select count('id') From 'users' where 'username'= '$username' AND 'hashed_password' = '$hash_password'"),0)==1 )? $user_id : false;
```

my query is correct, but I think there is some thing wrong with the query . 
please help me out.

the whole code is here

```
 <?php 
function user_exists($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
     return(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'")
    , 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
     return(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1")
    , 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_id_from_username($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("Select 'id' From 'users' where 'username'= '$username'"), 0 ,'id'));
}


function login($username,$password){
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $hash_password = md5($password);    
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("Select count('id') From 'users' where 'username'= '$username' AND 'hashed_password' = '$hash_password'"),0)==1 )? $user_id : false;
}

?>
```

Comment: `mysql_query` only returns a resource on success, otherwise it returns `false`. Check that the `mysql_query` is succeeding.

Comment: @user1836957 Have you checked the answer???

Answer (score 4):

Problem is with you used `''` around column_names. And it is treated as string not column_name

Change

```
 return (mysql_result(mysql_query("Select 'id' From 'users' where 'username'= '$username'"), 0 ,'id'));
```

to

```
return (mysql_result(mysql_query("Select `id` From `users` where `username`= '$username'"), 0 ,'id'));

return (mysql_result(mysql_query("Select count(`id`) From `users` where `username`=
'$username' AND `hashed_password` = '$hash_password'"),0)==1 )? $user_id : false;
```

Comment: OP, notice the difference between backticks `\`` and apostrophes `'`. I hated this when I was learning.